# how to retrieve one to many relationship data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two table

table#1

```
name_id |  name 
--------|-------
  1     | abc
  2     |  def
```

table#2

```
subject_id| name_id |subject
----------|---------|--------
1         | 1       |malayalam
2         | 1       | english
3         | 1       | hindi
4         | 2       | malayalam
5         | 2       | hindi
```

i want to join these two tables and get output in the following format

```
id |name |subject1  |subject2 |subject3
---|-----|--------- |---------|--------
1  |abc  |malayalam |english  |hindi
2  |def  |malayalam |hindi    |
```

is it possible in mySql?
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave my other answer up because again, I think you should really consider redesigning your DB schema. You're using MySQL so have you tried using `group_concat()` ? It's not going to put it in table form like that but will give you the expected data, where the different subjects will be in CSV form.

```
SELECT one.name_id as id, name, group_concat(subject) 
FROM one 
INNER JOIN two 
ON id = two.name_id 
GROUP BY id;
```

**Output**

```
1 | abc | malayalam, english, hindi
2 | def | malayalam, hindi
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not exactly sure about the scope of your schema here, because you have a `subject_id` that doesn't correlate to each `subject`. For example, `subject_id 1 = malayalam` but malayalm also equals `subject_id 3`, but `subject_id 3` also equals `hindi`, while again `hindi` is also assigned to `subject_id 4`. Very confusing schema to work with.

You mention it's a one to many, but without knowing more context I don't see that being the case. A person can have more than one subject. One subject can belong to more than 1 person. This is a many to many relationship, which means you *should* be using 3 tables here.

For the sake of your question, you can use an `inner join`

```
SELECT one.name_id as id, name, subject
FROM one 
INNER JOIN two
ON id = two.name_id
ORDER BY id;
```

The output of that query would be:

```
1 | abc | malayalam
1 | abc | english
1 | abc | hindi
2 | def | malayalam
2 | def | hindi
```

However, I would highly consider re-designing your database. I mean you want your data in that format, which looks nice with only 3 subjects. But what happens when there's 50 subjects for one person? Would you still want all subjects on one line like that? It's better to break it up, it will save you down the road when your database starts becoming more complex. In many cases, to create a many to many relationship you'll want a 3rd table that connects the two entities, in this case I'd create an `Enrolled_Classes` table to connect `Names` and `Subjects`

**Names**

```
name_id | name
--------------
1       | abc
2       | def
```

**Subjects**

```
subject_id | subject
--------------------
1          | malayalm
2          | english
3          | hindi
```

**Enrolled_Classes**

```
name_id | subject_id
--------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 1
2       | 3
```

Then you'd need another `join` for your query:

```
SELECT name, subject 
FROM Names 
INNER JOIN Enrolled_Classes 
ON Names.name_id = Enrolled_Classes.name_id 
INNER JOIN Subjects 
ON Enrolled_Classes.subject_id = Subjects.subject_id;
```

**Same Output**

```
abc | malayalam
abc | english
abc | hindi
def | malayalam
def | hindi
```

Comment: sorry, subject_id was the primary_key for that table#2. That was my mistake. this is not the result i am expecting. I need for a specific id data should be in one row :|